# could one integrate C++ unit testing into Xcode's XCTest?

Tags: c++, xcode, unit-testing, xctest

I have my own little cross-platform C++ unit testing framework where unit tests look like this:

```
#include "Test.h"

DEFINE_TEST(myTest) {
    AssertEqual(2+2, 4);
}
```

and are in .cpp files.

(Seems similar to the way [Catch](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch) does it, among others I'm sure)

I'd like to integrate this with Xcode, so I can run my tests using Xcode's Run Tests command and utilize [other tools](https://ship.io) which depend on unit tests being run that way. Ideally, I'd like each of my test cases to be a XCTest test case (though I'm fine with manually setting that up for each test) and I'd like my assertions (AssertEqual) to behave like XCTest's (XCTAssert).

**Is this possible? If so, how would I do it?**

(Note: not switching to just using XCtest because I'd like my tests to work on Windows as well)

Comment: Were you able to find a good way to do this in a cross platform way?

Answer (score 1):

Integrating with Xcode basically means ensuring:

- Each one of those tests ends up as a test method on a test case class.
- Every failing assertion sends `-[XCTestCase recordFailure:withDescription:inFile:atLine:expected:]` to the currently executing test case class instance.

Xcode will then populate the Test Navigator with all the runtime-discovered tests, organized under their test case class, after the first test run.

You might be able to do a large chunk of the work with macros to let the preprocessor build your test case class/es and methods at compile-time. Otherwise, you'd need to go through and hook everything up at runtime, before the test runner polls the runtime to discover all the `XCTestCase` subclasses and their test methods.